# Swift 1.2 Why cannot I subclass any NSCell's subclass?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nscell

Why can't I subclass any subclasses of NSCell? 
I would like to subclass `MyButtonCell`, which is `CustomButtonCell: NSButtonCell`. Meaning

```
class MyCustomButtonCell: MyButtonCell { }
```

always gives me the following errors:

```
<unknown>:0: error: declaration has a different @objc name from the declaration it overrides ('initTextCell:' vs. 'initWithTextCell:')
Custom_Controls.MyButtonCell:9:24: note: overridden declaration is here
  @objc @objc override init(textCell aString: String)
                       ^
<unknown>:0: error: declaration has a different @objc name from the declaration it overrides ('initImageCell:' vs. 'initWithImageCell:')
Custom_Controls.MyButtonCell:10:24: note: overridden declaration is here
  @objc @objc override init(imageCell image: NSImage?)
                       ^
```

Simple steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type: `swift` (if you have the latest Xcode 6.3.1)
3. When you get,

   > `Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.`

type the followings:

```
1> import AppKit
2> class Foo : NSCell {}
3> class Bar : Foo {}
```

4. You'll get these errors:

> `declaration has a different @objc name from the declaration it overrides ('initTextCell:' vs. 'initWithTextCell:')__lldb_expr_9.Foo:3:24: note: overridden declaration is here
>     @objc @objc override init(textCell aString: String)
>                          ^
>   declaration has a different @objc name from the declaration it overrides ('initImageCell:' vs. 'initWithImageCell:')__lldb_expr_9.Foo:4:24: note: overridden declaration is here
>     @objc @objc override init(imageCell image: NSImage?)
>                          ^`

Why? Is there a way around this problem?

FYI: Swift 1.1 didn't have this issue!

Comment: To answer some part of the “why” part of your question: NSCell has two init methods: `initTextCell:` and `initImageCell:`. Those don’t follow Cocoa naming conventions because they don’t have a “with” as part of their name. I think that’s what confuses the Swift compiler and makes it print something about `initWithTextCell:`. But I have no idea why this only happens in sub-subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that adding an init method that conforms to `NSCoding` removes the error:

```
import AppKit
class Foo : NSCell {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
class Bar : Foo {}
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Thanks a bunch. The error message was so misleading I did not think of this at all.